# Multi member member-driven LLC Bank Account without the personal presence of one the memebers

Tags: united-states, bank-account, limited-liability-company

We have an LLC which has two members (we both are foreigners), this LLC is member-driven.

We need to open a business bank account, but the problem is, that one of the members can't come to USA, is it possible to open an account in any US bank (WA,OR preferable) without the personal presence of one of the members?

May be something like LLC authorization resolution, that will authorize me or somebody else to open a business account?

Comment: Maybe you should contact the bank, since we are not lending and have no bearing on what a bank in Washington wants.

Comment: I have contacted two major banks and their representatives told me, that it is not possible, though there has to be a possibility to sign it with authorization resolution, as it was metioned below. I think, that banks in WA have the same rules, as banks in other states. So i thought someone would have an experience with such situation and can tell me what bank can accept resolution from one of the members saying that he authorizes another person to sign bank contract or at least any info on bank website about which can help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, i've contacted different banks, and only one bank (Wells Fargo) didn't say that they need all members in person, but gave me a form which my colleague filled to authorize me to open an account.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You'll have to call the bank and ask what documentation is required, I'm pretty sure they'll want notarized authorization by all partners, at least.

Comment: Do you have any experience in such case with specific bank?
I've talked with several bank representatives, but they all say, that all of the members must appear in person.

Comment: No, I don't. Since in LLC any member can take actions, I believe the banks you've talked to are trying to cover their assets.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will try to contact other banks.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. Anyone who thinks this is incorrect would care to comment?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, most banks will require all of the signers on the account to be present.  However, and this is the big however, the signers do not necessarily need to be the same people as the members.

You could have one of the members be the sole signer. You could have an outside accountant be the signer. Etc.

Regardless of who your signers are (ie, even if they are the same as the members) you will absolutely need a resolution from the members giving the signers authority to be signers.

So, for instance, if you personally will be present but the other member won't be, you will both need to sign the resolution appointing you as the signer.